# Core Data delete rules, delete all relationships and entities (many to many)

Tags: ios, core-data

I am having a hard time understanding how `Core Data` Delete Rules work. I have a `House` `Entity` has 2 `many to many` relationships. The related entities also have their own relationships to other entities.

When I delete the `House` entity I want to delete all entities that are in relationship to the parent (Room, Door, Window and Decks), and all the entities in relation to those sub entities.

[image]

What kind of delete rule do I need for something like this?

Comment: As an aside, are you sure you want many-many for the relationships?  eg. can a Room really belong to more than one House?  If they really are many-many, take care with using cascade in both directions: if houseA and houseB are both related to roomA, deleting houseA will cascade and delete roomA, which will cascade and delete houseB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The delete rule you are looking for is `Cascade` 
If you want a behavior wherein on *deletion of* `House` *all other entities are deleted*, then you'll need to setup `Cascade` delete rule on the both ends of the relationships.

Comment: On both ends of EVERY relationship?

Comment: @NicHubbard YES, if you desire the mentioned behavior, both ends!

Comment: @NicHubbard So, did you try it out? Is the problem solved now?

Comment: glad to hear that :)